# Remove toast when DownloadManager finished

Tags: android, android-download-manager

When a file downloaded with Android's `DownloadManager` finishes, it displays a `Toast` with the following text:

> The file has been saved to the Download folder

I'm wondering if there is anyway to remove it, because it is not accurate in my case. I've looked through the methods of `DownloadManger.Request` and I can't find anything that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download Manager don't give any completion  toast message from its side  until you register Broadcast Receiver with `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` `IntentFilter` and receive in app's activity in `BroadcasetReceiver.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method.

Answer (score 0):

- (Aubee elm. Android 5.1) don't shows toast.
- (Samsung Galaxy S8+ Android 7.0) don't show toast.
- (Kyocera AndroidOne Android 8.0 S2) don't show toast.
- (LGE LGL24 Android 5.0.2) SHOWS toast.
- (LGE LGV32 Android 6.0) SHOWS toast.

maybe it depends on customization by device maker. not depends on OS version.